# php function global defined variables do not work with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am having problems with some legacy code that I am trying to add to a Yii project.

It has to do with global variables, which I am well aware should instead be passed as parameters, but since this old code and is used in other projects rewriting it is not really and option.

```
$testVar = '123';
function testOutput() {
   global $testVar;
   var_dump($testVar);
}
testOutput();
```

Now if I include this file in a plain php file it works and outputs

```
string '123' (length=3)
```

But if I include this file in a Yii controller or even in a template it output this

```
null
```

I have tried to search for this issue but I just get a bunch of results about people using global variables incorrectly. I am sure it is not actually a Yii issue but most likely a php_ini setting that Yii is setting, but I can't find anything when searching the code or the Yii docs that would explain this.

This example can be tested by just creating a file with my first code block and then include it into a Yii template or controller. I even tested it with a clean example Yii project.

I hope I didn't hurt my chances of figuring this out by tagging this questiong with Yii since I have a feeling that it is not just a Yii specific issue.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you declared `$testVar = 123` inside a function/class, it is not global.

Comment: if you do `global $testVar; $testVar = 123;` at the begining before function definition, it will work, I just tested with Yii controller

Comment: @MarkoD you are right, but why is this? Any docs to say why this is needed and why the Yii framework causes this to be required? Also you put this as an answer and I would accept it.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. I'm not sure why it happens, I guess it's something on the line of what others have said...

Comment: @byoungb: it's because the scope in which $testVar is initially declared is NOT the global scope, so other scopes will not be able to access it.

Comment: @Wrikken oh I see since, the include file is being included within a function/class (Yii) it is not a global scope. Thanks. The note immediately before this section in the php docs I think explains it nicely. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) Thanks everyone for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do like this, it will work, I just tested with Yii controller

```
global $testVar;
$testVar = '123';
function testOutput() {
   global $testVar;
   var_dump($testVar);
}
testOutput();
```

Comment: Thanks!! Had the same issue. Why is this happening? do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

As DCoder mentioned, if youre declaring them inside a class, function/method then they are not global. You can try assigning them to the $_GLOBALS array though:

```
$GLOBALS['testVar'] = 123;
```

However depending on the legacy code and how youre integrating it you may need to change all references in that legacy code to use `$GLOBALS['thevar']` instead of `$thevar` or do an `extract($GLOBALS)` at the top of some or all of the legacy files.

Comment: The current code uses global variables mainly for a memcached connection object and a mysqli connection object that are used by several different functions and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Googled: [Global Variables in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13825-global-variables-in-yii/page__p__68111__hl__global+variable#entry68111)